# How to check if table exists in google big query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to check if a table exists in the google cloud bucket through a SQL query in Google Big Query.

In T-SQL I do it this way:

```
if object_id('TABELA') is null
begin
     create Tabela (
            campo tipo,
            campo2 tipo
     )
end
```

How do I perform this query in google bigquery?

Comment: What about using the DDL statement CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ....

See:  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_table_statement

This way the table will be created if it doesn't exist and left alone if it is already present.  You mentioned Google Cloud Storage in your original post but I am interpreting that as simply meaning that the original table exists in BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Most DBMSs (including BigQuery) have an INFORMATION_SCHEMA that holds information about the objects in a database. This would normally be the place to look for the answers to your type of question